# Google Cloud Messaging, receiving message, but not building notification

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented the Google Cloud Messaging for Android client on my app. When sent from our 3rd party server, we received a success message:

**EDITED**

So turns out I am actually receiving the message from the Google Cloud Messaging server, but I am not getting a notification on the phone. I know I am receiving the message because it shows it my Logcat. The only problem is that my notification is not getting built/sent.

Why is this happening? Please note my `GcmIntentService` is a separate class on its own. As well as the `BroadcastReceiver`. I am guessing it has to do with my `sendNotification()` method?

**IntentService**

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        // Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM will be extended in the future with 
        // new message types, just ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't recognize.
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } 

        else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());               
        }

        // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            // This loop represents the service doing some work.
            for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                Log.i("GCM", "Working... " + (i+1) + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
            Log.i("GCM", "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());

            // Post notification of received message.
            sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
            Log.i("GCM", "Received: " + extras.toString());
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

**BroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());

    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

}
```

Comment: are you getting your device id when check for register?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: @Saqib yes I am getting the `registration id` with no problems.

Comment: looks ok but just to try, change it `<service =".GCMIntentService" android:enabled="true" />` [to be noted GCM in capital]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out!!!

Turns out you need to have 3 things for every notification:

1. setSmallIcon()
2. setContentTitle()
3. setContextText()

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your response on your server with the 'fake_message_I'd in, you must have set the dry_run parameter in your message. This just validates the message without actually sending it. Remove that parameter and retest.

Comment: I just discovered this too and retested, but still not showing up on my phone.